# How to write the type signature of a function in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, types, type-signature

How do I write the type signature of this function in Haskell?

```
isEarlier (a, b) (x, y) = (a * 60 + b) < (x * 60 + y)
```

It decides if a date is earlier than the other one and print out True/False.

Comment: If you genuinely don't have a clue, you can try entering your function in GHCi and asking for the type that GHC infers for it. (By putting `:type isEarlier`.) But I'm curious as to why you have no idea about it? What do you think the type would be?

Comment: it doesn't "print out", it *returns* the Boolean result. if you try it at an interpreter's prompt, it (usually) does print out the returned value, but that printing is the *interpreter's* doing.

Answer (score 1):

```
isEarlier :: (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int) -> Bool
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low-quality answers.

Comment: that's one possibility. another is `isEarlier :: (Integer, Integer) -> (Integer, Integer) -> Bool`, yet another is `isEarlier :: (Float, Float) -> (Float, Float) -> Bool`. if we try `GHCi> :t let isEarlier (a, b) (x, y) = (a * 60 + b) < (x * 60 + y) in isEarlier` it says `isEarlier :: (Ord a, Num a) => (a, a) -> (a, a) -> Bool`. that's the most general type for it.